# Visual C# 2010 Express: Same Form But Different Size on Win7 and WinXP

Tags: c#, windows, forms, size

I'm using Visual C# Express 2010 both on my Win7 and XP.

I have a Windows Form Application project, and there is SevenXPForm (inherits Form).

I created it in Visual C# Express 2010 on Win7, and in the Properties panel, I set

```
.MinimumSize = 300, 300
.Size = 300, 300
```

And a TabControl is in the middle of the Form:

[image]

However, when I save the project/solution, and open in in Visual C# Express 2010 on WinXP, the size changed to:

```
.MinimumSize = 300, 279
.Size = 300, 279
```

And the TabControl is NOT it the middle of the Form any more:

[image]

When I open it on Win7 again, it comes back.

This is haunting me, cuz my application is expected to be working both on XP and Seven, (and Vista).

Do I have to set something to let it behave exactly same both on Win7 and WinXP?

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is that the borders around the form differ between Windows XP and Windows 7. This causes the window sizes to differ. How .NET tries to solve this is by instead of saving the size of the window as you see it in the property dialog, it actually saves the `ClientSize`, which is the inner size of the window. What you see in the property dialog is the size converted to include the outer borders. This means that when you open the project on Windows XP, which has smaller borders, .NET tries to adjust.

It looks like the problem you are seeing is an issue in the conversion. It does seem to take into account the smaller vertical size, but the smaller horizontal size is not taken into account.

Concerning your work around. A different approach to your specific problem/solution would be not to automatically resize the tab control, but to let .NET do this for you. If you set the `Padding` of the form to e.g. `10, 10, 10, 10` and set `Dock` of the tab control to `Fill`, you will get the same effect.

I don't see a general solution here though, because if this is an issue in the conversion that .NET itself does, this becomes very difficult.

Comment: Hi Pieter, thanks for your reply.  I does work, but if there are several controls on the form, I think we need to group them in a Panel.  My friend suggested me to make the Form.Size a little bigger than the Form.MinimumSize, and it works with the side effect.  Anyway, I will mark yours as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

After Googling a lot, I still cannot find a solution. But I do have a wordaround to partially solve my problem:

```
private void SevenXPForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tabControl1.Width = this.ClientSize.Width - tabControl1.Left * 2;
    tabControl1.Height = this.ClientSize.Height - tabControl1.Top * 2;
}
```

This is just a workaround, I think there should be a better way to do.

(What if there are a lot of controls on the form? Of course, we can put a panel as the sole  child control of the form, and then add all other controls into this panel, which works, but it's too tedious)

Comment: Hey Peter. Did you ever find a solution to this? I have a label printing app that basically draws all of the `Label` Controls during the OnPaint event. In Windows 7 (my development PC) everything is fantastic. When I swing over to our XP machines out in the plant, I have a certain group of `Label` Controls that are positioning themselves way off.

Answer (score 0):

A more robust workaround is to put the contents of the entire form in a panel with the docking set to fill, and then line up everything as you otherwise would in that panel. Until this issue is fixed -- assuming that it ever is -- I'd recommend doing this as a matter of course for every form you create.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look on this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229605.aspx

--

**Quick View**

Automatic scaling enables a form and its controls, designed on one machine with a certain display resolution or system font, to be displayed appropriately on another machine with a different display resolution or system font. It assures that the form and its controls will intelligently resize to be consistent with native windows and other applications on both the users' and other developers' machines. The support of the .NET Framework for automatic scaling and visual styles enables .NET Framework applications to maintain a consistent look and feel when compared to native Windows applications on each user's machine.

Answer (score 0):

It's old question, but it is in Google, so I have an answer, which may be useful for others, so I will share it (sorry for my English).

1) draw a panel1
2) `panel1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill` in **Form1_Load** section;
3) now you can use panel1 width and height to get real width and height of Form1, no matter which OS (Win XP or 7) you are using, no matter form border style.